# Populating a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with dictionary keys and values

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I have a dictionary that has as its keys a three letter country code, and as its values the name of the country.

```
Dictionary<string, string> CountryList=new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

I also have a DataGridView and a DataTable. What I'd like to do is to create a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn for certain columns in my DataTable-columns that display country information. So, for example, one of my columns in my DataTable is called `Country`, and I'd like for that column to have a drop down combo box that displays the name of the country, and that when selected, populates the cell in the DataTable with the key from the dictionary (the three letter code). However, I'm totally stumped as to how to do this. Do I have to set the DataSource to the keys, and the DisplayMember to the values? I tried that, and got an error:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn buildCountries = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
buildCountries.HeaderText = "List of Countries";
buildCountries.DataSource = CountryList.Keys.ToString();
buildCountries.DisplayMember = CountryList.Values.ToString();
```

> Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive but I think you won't be able to accomplish this the way you were trying. I know that this may be considered as heavy artillery but you could create a `DataTable` out of the `Dictionary` and do a `DataBinding` on it.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn buildCountries = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
buildCountries.HeaderText = "List of Countries";
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Keys");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Values");
KeyValuePair<string, string> [] array = CountryList.ToArray();
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in array)
{
        dataTable.Rows.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
buildCountries.DataSource = dataTable;
buildCountries.DisplayMember = "Values";
buildCountries.ValueMember = "Keys";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(buildCountries);
```

Answer (score 5):

With `Keys.ToString()`, you are creating a String which represents the Keys collection, not getting a list of keys.  This will return:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.String]

DisplayMember is the name of the property of each item in DataSource which should be shown in the ComboBox - this should probably be `"Value"`.

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> CountryList=new Dictionary<string, string>();

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn buildCountries = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
buildCountries.HeaderText = "List of Countries";
buildCountries.DataSource = CountryList.ToArray();
buildCountries.ValueMember = "Key";
buildCountries.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

`CountryList.ToArray()` will give you an array of `KeyValuePair<string, string>`s, which does implement IList.

If you want to get the selected country code, use `buildCountries.SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to set a dictionary as the datasource for a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

```
 buildCountries .DisplayMember = "Key";
 buildCountries .ValueMember = "Value";
 buildCountries .DataSource = new BindingSource(CountryList, null);
```