# Populate dagridview's Combobox select from sql

Tags: c#

i'm trying something like this:

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Column2 =new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();// Column2 is my datagridview's combobox
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select name from inventorymaster", con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            Column2 = (read["name"].ToString());

        }
        read.Close();
```

I get error:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to  'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn'

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what the problem is .. `Column2` is of Type `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` but you are assigning the object = to the string value `read["name"].ToString()` you should look into Binding the name from the sql result set into either a DataTable or a List<T> for example take a look at this posting for a working example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635109/populating-a-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-with-dictionary-keys-and-values

Comment: Can you give me code example?

Comment: can you do a simple google search I provided you with a link in my initial comment and I am not here to do the simple things for you in regards to executing a simple google search. you want to populate a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` then do a google search on how to populate a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. But i thought this forum was to get code answers for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM Inventorymaster", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            Column1.Items.Add(sqlReader["name"].ToString());
        }

        sqlReader.Close();
```